# `rm` everything in dir A that also exists in dir B

Tags: command-line

I accidentally `cp`'d a *bunch* of stuff from B into A without including the folder.  I.e. I copied the contents of B into A, and I meant to copy B into A to get A/B.  A already had a bunch of stuff in it, so now I have to sort it all out.  However, B still exists in its original location, so I can `ls B` to see what is in B.  Can I use this info to `rm` the stuff in A that is also in B?

Comment: Yes. It is trivial to use the output of ls to produce the list of files to rm -- unless you have characters like spaces and parentheses in the names which require an additional layer of quoting.

Answer (score 0):

got it.

from A:

`find B -maxdepth 1 -printf "%P\n" | xargs -d '\n' rm -rf`

Answer (score 0):

```
fdupes -d A B
```

fdupes is a really helpful utility for discovering and removing duplicate files.